# GraphQL filtering/sorting DatoCMS GatsbyJS

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I have the following GraphQL query:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query NewsQuery($slug: String!) {
    datoCmsNews(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
      id
      title
      description
      slug
      meta {
        publishedAt
      }
      cover {
        fluid(maxHeight: 530) {
          ...GatsbyDatoCmsSizes
        }
      }
    }
    allDatoCmsNews(sort: { fields: [meta___publishedAt], order: DESC }, limit: 4) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          title
          slug
          meta {
            publishedAt
            isValid
            status
          }
          cover {
            fluid(maxHeight: 375) {
              ...GatsbyDatoCmsSizes
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

On my `allDatoCmsNews` query how would I go about about sorting/filtering out a News item where a `$slug` is equal to the current slug? I don't want to show a News item if that news item is currently being viewed. I'm guessing I would have to use `neq` just struggling with the correct syntax.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pretty trivial using `filter`:

`allDatoCmsNews(sort: { fields: [meta___publishedAt], order: DESC }, limit: 4, filter: {slug: {ne: $slug}})`